# Aspnetboilerplate: Cannot write log to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, aspnetboilerplate

I want to write logs into SQL Server instead of file. I use the method `Logger.Debug()` but it writes nothing into SQL Server.

I have created a table HtcLog in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HtcLog] 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [Thread] [nvarchar] (255) NULL ,
    [Level] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL ,
    [Logger] [nvarchar] (255) NULL ,
    [Message] [nvarchar] (4000) NOT NULL , 
    [Exception] [nvarchar] (2000) NULL , 
)
```

I have modified `log4net.config` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>      
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender_SQLServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,System.Data,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=192.168.50.60;initial catalog=test_db;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO HtcLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception], [CreationTime]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @log_date)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%p" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%c" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%m" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_SQLServer" />
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

but it didn't work.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue? Does ABP support writing logs to DB?

Comment: It's not ABP that logs, it's log4net. This has nothing to do with ABP. And yes, it does write to databases. Did you *load* the configuration with `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`? Please post your log4net configuration code

Comment: BTW using a SQL login, especially the `sa` account for logging, is not a good idea.

Comment: It worked well with file but not sql server that's why i thought there're something wrong with ABP.
Here after the log4net configuration in ABP (Startup.cs):
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 //
 // Do something
 //
 
 // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
 return services.AddAbp<HTCMobileWebHostModule>(
  // Configure Log4Net logging
  options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
   f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
  )
 );
}